# issue compiling tex file from journal

Tags: packages

I have a file template downloaded from:
http://www.radioeng.cz/info/10-guidelines-for-authors.htm
I tried to compile the original tex file without modification,
I got the following error.
[image: attached image]

Answer (score 1):

The class file you downloaded requires the file newtxtext.sty (and others) in order to compile. You can see which packages are required by looking in the class file. I believe you can get newtxtext by installing the [newtx package](http://ctan.org/pkg/newtx).